# Why is this kivy code not working?

Tags: python, kivy

my kivy code is supposed to display filechooser and allow a user to choose an image as the background image.The upload image button is showing but nothing happens when a user clicks it.

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView, FileChooserIconView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), random(), random())
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color)
            d = 30.
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]

class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        painter = MyPaintWidget()
        Choose = Button(text = 'upload image')
        parent.add_widget(painter)
        parent.add_widget(Choose)

        def chooose_file(obj):
            fc = FileChooserIconView(title= 'upload image')
            image_path = self.fc.selection[0]
            image_name = file_path.split('/')[-1]

            with self.canvas.before:
                Rectangle(
                    size=self.size,
                    pos=self.pos,
                    source=image_name)
            Choose.bind(on_release=choose_file) 
        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Comment: Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
add this to your build method

Comment: Close voter: I can't see how a working example could be a lot shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if you have an indentation error but it looks like you are binding your button inside the method that is supposed to be bound (since it never gets called your button is never bound)

Answer (score 0):

You need to de-indent:

```
    Choose.bind(on_release=choose_file)
return parent
```

to be:

```
Choose.bind(on_release=choose_file)
return parent
```

At the moment it will only be called when choose_file is called, which is too late, as you want it to be bound before not after.